# What to learn to be able to send files online using c++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, file-transfer

### What to learn to be able to send files online using c++ on windows ?

i know c++, and i got a program that does some benchmark and saves into a text file, i want that text file to be sent to me after the benchmarking is done, so what should i search for ? tried searching found something called sockets and something about server and clients in linux, kinda dunno what to search for.

this isn't a homework, just want to do it for fun xD, and would help me in future if i want someone who knows nothing about whats happening to test something for me (the file would have all i need and it will be sent to me).

Comment: Well, you can send by email.. If that solves your problem then just focus your research on how to send emails through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you better off just emailing the file after a benchmark is done, and doing it using some bash or Python scripting rather than C++ or any other low level language. Here is an [example of sending email using Python](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html). Another option would be to upload to the FTP or use rsync to transfer file over SSH. And in any case, do not write your own client-server application for this.

If you still want to use C++, here is an example of [sending email using POCO](http://blog.neofig.com/2011/01/30/send-mail-by-poco-cpp-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

you will find some official documentation on Win32 sockets here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This tutorial seems pretty good and simple:
http://johnnie.jerrata.com/winsocktutorial/

Have a nice day!